# add custom class to wp_nav_menu using filter hook nav_menu_css_class

Tags: menus

I have a custom post type in my wordpress theme. I want to add a custom class to the nav menu for the pages created in that custom post type. I read that you can use a filter hook: "nav_menu_css_class", but my php chops are pretty limited. How do I set up that filter hook to apply only to my custom post type pages in the nav menu and give them a custom class?

Answer (score 8):

here is a simply example:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'auto_custom_type_class', 10, 2 );
function auto_custom_type_class($classes, $item) {

    if ($item->type_label == "CUSTOM_TYPE_NAME"){
        $classes[] = "New_Class";
    }

    return $classes;
}
```

just change `CUSTOM_TYPE_NAME` to the name of your custom post type and `New_Class` with the name of your class and paste this snippet in your theme's functions.php file.

Comment: That works. Appreciate it!

Comment: Glad i could help.

Comment: Another question: `$item->type_label` Where does this come from and are there other things you can apply to this variable "$item" ?

Comment: the $item object is passed by the apply_filters call and it holds all of the item variables. you can get a list of the by adding somewhere in the function `var_dump($item);`

Comment: Wow, sweet! (just ran it) Good to know. Thanks again.

Comment: One more question (hopefully the last) ;)
Is it possible to look for REGEX match in the spot where it says "CUSTOM_TYPE_NAME"? I have been trying to figure it out using preg_match, but I am lost.

Comment: Yes it is but to do what?